# Transform RS232 input into keyboard events in windows

Tags: windows, keyboard, hook, inject

I need to inject keyboard events into the operating system (windows).

The overall picture is that I need to convert a RS232 device (similar to barcode scanner) to a "usb keyboard emulated device". There is a background application that controls the rs232 device and as soon at it receives data, data should be converted to keyboard events to be received by the active application, a Point Of Sale application.

I know how to capture events by using windows hooks but I'm not sure whether new events can be queued into the system and how that can be done.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If I get your question correctly, you may want to have look at `SendInput(...)` here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx

Since you didnt specify the language, I assumed C.

Eg:

```
    INPUT inp;

    memset(&inp, 0, sizeof(INPUT));
    inp.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inp.ki.wVk = VK_ESCAPE;
    SendInput(1, &inp, sizeof(INPUT)); //send keyDown Event
    inp.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    SendInput(1, &inp, sizeof(INPUT)); //send KeyUp Event
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not capture the serial port entry as event and re-emit the keys [the SendKeys class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send.aspx) ? Drivers are quite complicated to write/test (buggy driver can close BSOD )
In what language are you planning to do it ?

Comment: My natural language is Java, but I wasn't sure whether it could be done in Windows without complex integration with native libraries.
Fortunately solution is not that difficult after all, there is an equivalent SendKeys in java -Robot- and the serial driver is already half-done in Java.
Finally, all boils down to create the driver normally, transforming the rs232 input and use the Robot class to send key events to the active application.
Thanks

Comment: If anyone interested, another part of the project is to hook keyboard events to start/stop messages coming in. Again, is straightforward using jintellitype library.
http://melloware.com/products/jintellitype/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You probably should start looking at BlockInput/SendInput.

These came out after I made my app.  I use PostMessage to post WM_KEYDOWN/WM_KEYUP messages to the active window.  This is effective, but has a variety of issues.  (For example, you have to set the keyboard shift state to do capitals.  Thunderbird requires you to send backspaces slowly.)